# Select dynamic cell in VBa

Tags: vba, cell

I have a few columns (B to G), starting numbers in B3. Today I select data and copy it with macro into cell B3. Tomorrow I want the data copied to cell B4, the day after to B5.

When the month is over data should be copied to C3, ....

Now I have to change the desired B3, B4 everyday in the macro. How to do it automaticaly.

thanks in advance

Part of code:

```
Range("B47").Formula = "=SUM(B46-C46)"
Range("B47").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("VIP Punten").Select
Range("C33").Select "THIS HAS TO CHANGE EVERYDAY"
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: [Find the last cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)?

Comment: obligatory: [don't use select and activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) (generally)

Comment: Rather than trying to select a cell dynamically, learn how to do what you want to do while selecting no cells at all. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248) (same link as @Warcupine gave, but hearing it twice can't hurt).

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the last row and the last column of your table.

```
Dim last_row As Long
Dim last_column As Long

last_column = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, last_column).End(xlUp).Row
```

This you can apply to your code like:

```
Dim last_row As Long
Dim last_column As Long


Range("B47").Formula = "=SUM(B46-C46)"
Range("B47").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("VIP Punten").Select

last_column = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, last_column).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(last_row , last_column ).Select "THIS HAS TO CHANGE EVERYDAY"
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Other advise: For optimise your code try to avoid use `.Select` is more optimal  cut it like this

**Before:**

```
Cells(last_row , last_column ).Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

**After:**

```
Cells(last_row , last_column ).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I hope I have helped you :)

Comment: When I do so, text comes in to G1, but should come in B3

Comment: Okay, thats because you have headers and I didn't know it. I have modified my code, try now

Comment: text is going to right column, but goes to last line instead of line B3

Comment: My failure, I thought that you only have one row for the header. However, you have two rows (B1, B2). Try know, I have only change the row that starts to count for the last column.

Comment: It is still not correct. So, I have Column A for the date, B for the Data. So, today the data from Cell B47 in Sheet A has to be copied to Sheet B, Cell B3. Tomorrow, data from Cell B47 in Sheet A has to be copied to Sheet B, Cell B4, ....

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried

Dim ValueCell as Variant

Dim wb1 as workbook

ValueCell = wb1.sheets("Blad1").range("B2").value

wb1.sheets("Blad2").range("D1") = ValueCell"

But get error on ValueCell = ....